# Sapper router appending instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

If i click on a link in my sapper application, the new route is appended to the `_layout` `<slot>` instead of replacing it.

The following is an example, first, the DOM before the link was clicked:

```html
<div id="sapper>
    <main>
      <!-- This is is the index.svelte page -->
    </main>
</div>
```

Then after clicking a link:

```html
<div id="sapper>
    <main>
      <!-- This is the index.svelte page -->
    </main>
    <main>
      <!-- This is a subpage -->
    </main>
</div>
```

Has anyone encountered this before? How could I troubleshoot this?

Comment: This looks like a HMR issue... What's your setup? (bundler: webpack / rollup, svelte plugin you're using, starter project, maybe bundler config if it differs significantly from default starter)

Comment: It's bundled with rollup and the only significant change is, postcss preprocessing..

Comment: So now it looks like a SSR issue... Can you double check output in your terminal and console? Don't you have an error popping somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure? does the app do a server roundtrip for routing? There is no error showing in the console..

Comment: No indeed, not for client-side routing... I have seen this bug already, but it generally indicated an error in my code. Sometimes Sapper can swallow errors unfortunately. Another time, I saw that when playing (unsuccessfully) with page transitions... Maybe try to debug what's happening from `src/node_modules/@sapper/internal/App.svelte`?

Comment: Wow, Thanks for the tip. It actually had to do with a transition on my Nav component, not sure what caused it exactly though..